# Checking availability of Getters and Setters in Java

Tags: java

I have a class Book with private variables bookName(type:String), bookPrice (type:int),authorName(type:String).I have included appropriate getters and setters methods for these private variables.

Another class TestBook created which has main method.I need to get the details bookName,bookPrice,authorName from user.

Object for book class created in Testbook class and assign the value for its attributes using the setters. Also to print the output output using the getters method.

I wrote the entire code but getting failure.

Fail1 : Check availability of getter/setter of bookName attribute
Fail2 : Check availability of getter/setter of bookPrice attribute
Fail3 : check availbility of getter/setter of authorName attribute

Book.java

```
 public class  Book {

         private String bookName;
         private int bookPrice;
         private String authorName;

         //getters

         public String getbookName(){
             return bookName;
         }

        public String getauthorName(){
              return authorName;
        }
        public int getbookPrice(){
            return bookPrice;
        }

       //setters


        public void setbookName(String newName){
             this.bookName = newName;
        }
        public void setbookPrice(int bokPrice){
            this.bookPrice = bokPrice;
        }
        public void setauthorName(String author){
            this.authorName = author;
        }


    }
```

TestBook.java

```
 import java.util.Scanner;

     class TestBook {

         public static void main(String[] args){
         Scanner my = new Scanner(System.in);

         String name1,name2;
         int num;

        // Getting user input

        System.out.println("Enter the Book name:");
        name1 = my.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Enter the price:");
        num = my.nextInt();

        String re = my.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Enter the Author name:");
        name2 = my.nextLine();

        //Setting values of private variable using setters

        Book myObj = new Book();
        myObj.setbookName(name1);
        myObj.setbookPrice(num);
        myObj.setauthorName(name2);

        //Printing values using getters

        System.out.println("Book Details");
        System.out.println("Book Name :"+myObj.getbookName());
        System.out.println("Book Price :"+myObj.getbookPrice());
        System.out.println("Author Name :"+myObj.getauthorName());



        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`getbookName()` should be `getBookName()`. `setbookName()` should be `setBookName()` and so on, for **all** of your getter(s) and setter(s). That is the correct Java convention. And I can only assume the criteria your tester is looking for.

Comment: Thank you so much. It just worked. Amazing and unbelievable. Thanks a lot again.